# R finding relative maximum from outliers

Tags: r, outliers, max

Suppose I have a vector of numbers that I want to find a general cutoff for. For example:

```
x <- c(35, 2, 3, 30, 1, 4, 33, 6, 36)
```

In this case, I would want to only extract a subset that countains `35, 30, 33, 36`. In this case the cutoff would be at `30` Without hardcoding a definite cutoff, I would like my code to adapt to different vectors of numbers in order to find that cutoff.

Another example would be:

```
x <- c(1, 20, 42, 13, 118, 149, 130, 30, 11, 32, 120, 0.5, 0.03)
```

In this case, a reasonable cutoff would be around `118`.

Currently I am hard coding the cutoffs because I am dealing with simple cases, however I would like to make this process more modular for more variable vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `quantile` function

```
cutoff <- function(y, prob=0.7) y[y > quantile(y, prob)]

x <- c(35, 2, 3, 30, 1, 4, 33, 6, 36)
cutoff(x)
[1] 35 33 36

x <- c(1, 20, 42, 13, 118, 149, 130, 30, 11, 32, 120, 0.5, 0.03)
cutoff(x)
[1] 118 149 130 120
```

And you can define a different probability as desired

```
cutoff(x, 0.8)
[1] 149 130 120
```